# Data structure for user data in a web app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, data-structures

I'm building a web app and I'm not sure about the structure of my database in mongodb. I would want to use a collection for users with their contacts data and everytime a new user registers I want to create a new collection related to him linked by their user _id.

It's this a good process to manage data in mongodb or it's better to use a unique collection?

#### Final result:

```
// User collection
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId('...')
    username: ''
    password: ''
    ... //many data
  }
... // many users
]

// User related Collection
{
  _id: ObjectId('...') // the same of user collection
  ... //many data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create one user collection, within that can keep user relation information. If information related to users needs different collection then you can go for an embedded document.